# How to do prediction in batches using data loaders for hugging face models

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I have fine-tuned hugging face model. Now instead of doing inferencing on single data point. I want to somehow use data-loaders for batch inferencing.

How can I change the below code to do batch inferencing?

```
def inhouse_model(row) -> "pos or neg class":
    """
            This function takes input as text and return the multilabel score
            :param row:
            :return: pos or neg
            """

    tokenizer = tr.RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("model/")
    inputs = tokenizer(row.text, return_tensors="pt",truncation=True)



    
    model = tr.RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("model/",
                                                                problem_type="single_label_classification",
                                                                num_labels=2,
                                                                ignore_mismatched_sizes=True,
                                                                id2label={0: 'negative', 1: 'positive'})
    outputs = model(**inputs)[0]
    

    score = outputs.detach().numpy()
    
    score = softmax(score, axis=1)[:, 1]
```

Comment: By looking at [the docs](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/db7d6a80e82d66127b2a44b6e3382969fdc8b207/src/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py#L2360) it looks as though you can just pass `row` as a list of rows and it will return a batched set of inputs, which should innately be able to be passed through your model.

Comment: Data loaders would be faster, I guess?

Comment: Dataloaders are good because they can process data alongside the GPU processing. If you create a Dataloader which returns a list of your `row.text`s then I believe it would be faster.